# m4_toupper returns empty string for variable

Tags: bash, autotools, autoconf, m4

I want to print out a string variable in upper case. I'm trying to use the [`m4_toupper`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Text-processing-Macros.html) macro, but my variable seems to be ignored.

For example, given the following code:

```
foobar="linux-gnu"
echo "${foobar}"
echo m4_toupper("x${foobar}")
echo "${foobar}"
```

Results in the following output:

```
linux-gnu
X
linux-gnu
```

Since the `x` is capitalized, I suspect that the m4 macro is working correctly, but perhaps not receiving my variable string -- yet, the `echo` statements seem to work fine. Why is an empty string being returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your macro isn't ignored, it just gets evaluated at a different time than you're expecting.
The M4sugar macros are evaluated when `configure` is *created*.  You seem to want to have the toupper function applied when `configure` is *run*.  You can do it at creation time by something like:

```
m4_define([thestring], [linux-gnu])dnl
m4_define([thexstring], [x])dnl
m4_append([thexstring], m4_toupper(thestring))dnl
foobar="thestring"
echo "${foobar}"
echo "thexstring"
echo "${foobar}"
```

but this won't help if `foobar` is set up at runtime.  Then you'll have to resort to one of the runtime techniques suggested by Fredrik Pihl (or something similar).

In any case, `m4_toupper("x${foobar}")` is changed to `"X${FOOBAR}"` so that's why it's not appearing, since `${FOOBAR}` is not defined in the environment.

Comment: Interesting that you mention m4 sugar. I tried going through the m4 questions once and tagging those that are related to the autotools with the m4sh tag, and someone rolled back all the edits and removed the m4sh tags!

Comment: Why'd they do that?  That seems to be a useful classification.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about m4 macro, but here are some ways to convert a variable to uppercase:

```
$ echo $foobar | awk '{print toupper($0)}'
LINUX-GNU

$ echo $foobar | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'
LINUX-GNU

$ echo ${foobar^^}
LINUX-GNU
```